# How to use "kill -HUP" to reload python program in linux

Tags: python, process, kill

I have a python program in linux

```
  server: ps -ef | grep -i ashe
    
    root 26388     1  0 13:51 pts/3    00:00:00 /opt/app/ashe/python3/bin/python3.6 /opt/app/ashe/ashe_parser.py
    
    root 32578     1  8 08:05 ?        00:31:09 /opt/app/ashe/python3/bin/python3.6 /opt/app/ashe/ashe_ticketer.py
```

This program process some data and send the log to log files.

However, there is other program that rotate and archive these logs at some time. Once that happen then the python program is not able to log anything to the new created files.

The reason seems that the python program still member these rotated files.

```
server:/opt/app/ashe/ashe_logs:  lsof | grep -i ashe | grep -i log | grep -i python3.6 

python3.6 26388    root    4w      REG              253,3     8414    540277 /opt/app/ashe/ashe_logs/ticketing.log.bak_20200811_115123 (deleted) 

python3.6 32578    root    4w      REG              253,3     8414    540277 /opt/app/ashe/ashe_logs/ticketing.log.bak_20200811_115123 (deleted)
```

I tried "kill -HUP" to reload the python program but it terminates it instead. With "pkill -HUP" it does not terminate it but it does not do anything else.

Any idea please how to fix this from linux side or from the python program itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`kill -HUP <pid>` will kill your process by default. If you need to change your program action when log file changed, you can use signal handler. When logfile configuration changed, send `SIGHUP` signal to your process. When signal occur, your signal handler will work. In signal handler you can do what you want

In below example `print()` func's message will go to the terminal(in interactive mode). If `SIGHUP` signal come, `SIGHUP_handler` will run and it will change the `stdout` direction to the "filename" file

```
import signal,sys

print("hello")

def SIGHUP_handler(signum,frame):
    """
    stdout will go to the "filename" file
    """
    sys.stdout=open(filename,"a")


signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP,SIGHUP_handler) # set signal handler

signal.pause() # wait for a signal
print("world")
```

You need to modify this example according to your logging configuration. This is simple example